# How to find maximum of previous x elements using numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

## Question

Is there a way using numpy to sort maximum of range of previous x numbers?

## Example

Array of `[1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 8, 2, 3]`, and the range is 3

The output should be `[nan, nan, nan, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8]`.

The first three elements has no 3 previous numbers, so the result is nan.

The fourth elements (2) has the previous numbers of 1, 3, 4, therefore the max is 4.

Sorry for the misleading.

I will provide a second example.

Original array: `[1, 3, 4, 6, 2, 8, 2, 3, 1, 2]`
Output: `[nan, nan, nan, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 3]`

For the last element of output: 3, the reason in the 7th, 8th and 9th elements in original array are 2, 3, 1, therefore the max is 3.

Thanks!

Comment: Step 1: look up how to access a slice of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `pandas` solution:

```
win_size = 3
lst = [1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 8, 2, 3]

result = pd.Series(lst).rolling(win_size).max().shift(1).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[nan, nan, nan, 4.0, 4.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0]
```

Note: Outputs are floats - if that bothers you, feel free to convert.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `nan` in an `np.array` that is of data type int, so you can do the following. Change dtype to `.astype(float)`. Set the first 3 values to the minimum of the array minus 1. Sort the values. Change the new minimum values of the first 3 numbers to `np.nan`.

Note, sorting with `np.nan`, puts the `nan` values at the end, which is why I didn't change the values until after sorting.

```
a = np.array([1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 8, 2, 3]).astype(float)
a[np.arange(3)] = np.min(a-1)
a=np.sort(a)
a[np.arange(3)] = np.nan
a

array([nan, nan, nan,  2.,  2.,  3.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  8.])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maximum.accumulate` to get an iterative max

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 8, 2, 3])
a = np.maximum.accumulate(a).astype('float')
```

Converting to float is necessary to set values to `np.nan` in a numpy array. This clears the unwanted values.

```
a[np.arange(3)] = np.nan
a
```

Out:

```
array([nan, nan, nan,  4.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  8.,  8.,  8.])
```

---

For shifted rolling max with numpy if pandas is not an option

```
a =  np.array([1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 8, 2, 3])
window = 3
rolling = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(len(a)-window, window), strides=a.strides + a.strides)
np.r_[[np.nan]*window, np.max(rolling, axis=1)]
```

Out:

```
array([nan, nan, nan,  4.,  4.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  8.,  8.])
```

Comment: I'm better at pandas and not great with numpy. In my answer I was using `a[[0,1,2]]`, but I changed to `a[np.arange(3)]` after seeing your answer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: what if I only need the max of the previous 3 numbers, but not all?

Comment: @ TinlokCheung kindly give an example of expected output in that scenario.

Comment: Original array: [1, 4, 6, 8, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5]

Output: [nan, nan, nan, 6, 8, 8, 8, 3, 3, 4]

For the seventh element of output: 3
The reason is 4th, 5th, 6th elements in original array are 2, 3, 1, therefore the max is 3.